# Is it known whether the “sum of 3 cubes” problem has any parametric solution for integers other than 1 or 2 or multiples?

Tags: diophantine-equations

For example, it is known that for all t,
$$
(9t^4)^3 + (3t - 9t^4)^3 + (1 - 9t^3)^3 = 1
$$
and
$$
(1 + 6t^3)^3 + (1 - 6t^3)^3 + (-6t^2)^3 = 2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Cubic surface is rational. This means that there are 2-parametric parametrisation.

See this  [https://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/4cubes.html](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/4cubes.html)